# Allow browser microphone permissions in flutter drive

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, e2e-testing, flutter-integration-test

We need to automate e2e tests using flutter integrations package. but there is no way to bypass the permissions for the microphone. I have checked the answers here but none its working for google chrome.

Does someone know how to launch the flutter drive chrome instance with these flags ??
'--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',

I have tried many things and nothing works, I need to automate some e2e tests that requires to use the microphone, is there a solution for this ? I have checked the flutter integrations package , its for chrome on web.

Or is it possible to make flutter drive run on an already running chrome instance?